# Run method from jar file they have extends a Class

Tags: java

Can i run a method from am Plugin like onEnable(), my script doesnt work. :(

The extended Class:

```
package de.R3N3PDE.X.API;
import de.R3N3PDE;

public class JavaPlugin{
    Server server;
    public ServerManager getServer(){
        return new ServerManager(server);
    }

    public ServerManager setServer(Server s){
        server = s;
    }

    public PluginLogger getLogger(){
        return new PluginLogger(server);
    }
}
```

The Plugin:

```
package de.R3N3PDE.PluginExample;
import de.R3N3PDE.X.API.JavaPlugin;

public class PluginExample extends JavaPlugin{
    public void onEnable(){
        getLogger().info("Plugin Enabled!");
    }
}
```

The PluginLoader:

```
package de.R3N3PDE.X.Plugin;
imports de.R3N3PDE.X.API.JavaPlugin;

public void initPlugins(){
    try {
        File loc = new File("plugins");
        extendClasspath(loc);

        ServiceLoader<JavaPlugin> sl = ServiceLoader.load(JavaPlugin.class);
        Iterator<JavaPlugin> apit = sl.iterator();
        while (apit.hasNext()){;
            JavaPlugin met = apit.next();
            //Set the Server
            med.setServer(s);
            //run void onEnable(); in the Plugin????
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

====================

EDIT: 
Thanks. I have a new Problem... 
The URLClassLoader find Plugins but the ServiceLoader can´t load the Plugin.
I think the ServiceLoader cant fint the extended class.

The Plugin:

```
package de.R3N3PDE.PluginExampleName;
import de.CodingDev.X.Server.API.JavaPlugin;

public class PluginExampleName extends JavaPlugin{
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        System.out.println("Test");
        getLogger().info("Plugin Enabled!");
    }
}
```

I have make a new Plugin Loader the old version dosen´t work:

```
public void onLoad(){
    File loc = new File("plugins");

    File[] flist = loc.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {return file.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar");}
    });
    URL[] urls = new URL[flist.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < flist.length; i++)
        urls[i] = flist[i].toURI().toURL();
    URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    for(URL url : ucl.getURLs()){
        s.getLogger().info("PluginLoader", "Found Plugin: " + url.getFile());
    }
    ServiceLoader<JavaPlugin> sl = ServiceLoader.load(JavaPlugin.class, ucl);

    Iterator<JavaPlugin> apit = sl.iterator();
    while (apit.hasNext()){
        s.getLogger().info("PluginLoader", "Loading Plugin");
        apit.next().onEnable();
    }
}
```

The Log:

[LOG] [02.11.2013 15:26:09] [PluginLoader] [INFO] Loading Plugins...

[LOG] [02.11.2013 15:26:09] [PluginLoader] [INFO] Found Plugin: /C:/Users/René/Desktop/Server/plugins/CommandLogger.jar

Comment: Is the `met` the same as `med`? Is it a typo or I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes met is the same as med, it was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about making your class abstract with abstract onEnable method?

```
public abstract class JavaPlugin{
    Server server;
    public ServerManager getServer(){
        return new ServerManager(server);
    }

    public ServerManager setServer(Server s){
        server = s;
    }

    public PluginLogger getLogger(){
        return new PluginLogger(server);
    }

    public abstract void onEnable();
}
```

And then you have to implement onEnable method in your subclasses.
You could then call the onEnable method of any dynamically generated subclass that extends the JavaPlugin.

The second way could be implementing the onEnable method in Javaplugin and then overriding the method in an extended class.

```
public class JavaPlugin {
    ...
    public void onEnable(){
        getLogger().info("JavaPlugin onEnable default implementation!");
    }
}
```

In your PluginExample file:

```
public class PluginExample extends JavaPlugin{
    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
        getLogger().info("Plugin Enabled!");
    }
}
```

Comment: The "PluginExample" is a Example class, the classname is dynamicly

Comment: check out new suggestions

Comment: check out my question on the top After:
====================
EDIT: